# How to get multiple values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a set of file names to names and file types.

However, I get an error as follows.

What is the correct method to do it?

Thanks.

The dataframe is:

```
             full_name
0            ocean.jpg
1            mountain.png
2            forest.gif
3            river.mp4
4            animal.avi
5            girl.pdf

df[['name', 'type']] = df['full_name'].str.split('.')
KeyError: "['name' 'type'] not in index"
```

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Option1***
**`split`** with **`tolist`** if you just want the result

```
pd.DataFrame(df.full_name.str.split('.').tolist(), columns = ['name', 'type'])

       name type
0     ocean  jpg
1  mountain  png
2    forest  gif
3     river  mp4
4    animal  avi
5      girl  pdf
```

***Option 2*** (You were very close to this one)
**`split`** with **`expand=True`** if you want to edit original dataframe

```
df[['name', 'type']] = df['full_name'].str.split('.', expand=True)

      full_name      name type
0     ocean.jpg     ocean  jpg
1  mountain.png  mountain  png
2    forest.gif    forest  gif
3     river.mp4     river  mp4
4    animal.avi    animal  avi
5      girl.pdf      girl  pdf
```

Comment: Happy to help! You were super close on your own, I just wanted to present the first option in case you just wanted the result and didn't want to keep the old column.

Comment: How about using apply?

Comment: Apply is going to be slower since it's just masking iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `extract` with named groups.

```
In [232]: df.full_name.str.extract('(?P<name>\w+).(?P<type>\w+)', expand=True)
Out[232]:
       name type
0     ocean  jpg
1  mountain  png
2    forest  gif
3     river  mp4
4    animal  avi
5      girl  pdf

In [233]: df.join(df.full_name.str.extract('(?P<name>\w+).(?P<type>\w+)', expand=True))
Out[233]:
      full_name      name type
0     ocean.jpg     ocean  jpg
1  mountain.png  mountain  png
2    forest.gif    forest  gif
3     river.mp4     river  mp4
4    animal.avi    animal  avi
5      girl.pdf      girl  pdf
```

Comment: Thank you, Zero. Your answer is more advanced as it requires knowledge of regular expression.